# i18n translation partially works in node express app with handlebars support

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, internationalization

My problem is that english translation never used when I visiting `?lang=en` query parameter url. However Hungarian text change works well, showing `text to test on hungarian` in the default hu language without problem. What went wrong?

app.js:

```
var express        = require('express'),
    bodyParser     = require('body-parser'),
    cookieParser   = require('cookie-parser'),
    exphbs         = require('express-handlebars'),
    i18n           = require('i18n');
var app = express();

app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
  extname: '.hbs',
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  helpers: {
    __: function() { return i18n.__.apply(this, arguments); },
    __n: function() { return i18n.__n.apply(this, arguments); }
  }
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/', require('./routes/portfolio'));

i18n.configure({
  locales: ['hu', 'en'],
  fallbacks: {'en': 'hu'},
  defaultLocale: 'hu',
  cookie: 'locale',
  queryParameter: 'lang',
  directory: __dirname + '/locales',
  directoryPermissions: '755',
  autoReload: true,
  updateFiles: true,
  api: {
    '__': '__',  //now req.__ becomes req.__
    '__n': '__n' //and req.__n can be called as req.__n
  }
});
app.use(i18n.init);
```

views/portfolio.hbs:

```
<span id="text">{{{__ "text to test"}}}</span>
```

locales/hu.json:

```
{
    "text to test": "text to test on hungarian"
}
```

locales/en.json:

```
{
    "text to test": "text to test on english"
}
```

Full console log on start:

```
  i18n:debug will use C:\www\node\lantosistvan\locales\hu.json +0ms
  i18n:debug read C:\www\node\lantosistvan\locales\hu.json for locale: hu +5ms
  i18n:debug will use C:\www\node\lantosistvan\locales\en.json +3ms
  i18n:debug read C:\www\node\lantosistvan\locales\en.json for locale: en +1ms
  lantosistvan-portfolio:server Listening on port 3000 +16ms
  i18n:warn WARN: No locale found - check the context of the call to __(). Using hu as current locale +5s
GET /about-me?lang=en 304 90.678 ms - -
```

Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing to order of the routers and i18n.configure looks like solved it, so you have to place i18n before the router calls.